# Web API JSON Formatter StringEscapeHandling ignored

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

When I do this:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml;`
```

and then hit this endpoint:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public object TestApi()
 {
     return new {test = "<script>alert('o hai');</script>"}; 
 }
```

it returns the unescaped string. All of the examples I've seen of the StringEscapeHandling are those manually using JsonConvert.SerializeObject.

Other JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings that I set work just fine except for that one. Is this not supported?

Comment: It is actually returns escaped string. Check raw message with fiddler for example

Comment: @AlekseyL. you're absolutely right. I was looking in the wrong spot. Thanks for catching that!